# Check if the required file runs properly

Tags: php

I have function which is dynamically require files. Some files could have errors, and in this case the whole page will fail at this point.

Is there some way to check if any error will appear in the required file, and if everything is OK load the file, if something is wrong show error? Something like this:

```
try{
    require( "./formfunctions/" . $file . ".php" );

    $result = $returnValue;
} catch(Exception $e){
   $result = '<strong>Loading form failed. Please contact Sys Admin about this</strong>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah if you're using PHP 7 you can do it like:

```
try {
    require 'error.php';
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the errors in php file with this command **php -f** :

```
$output = shell_exec('php -l inc.php');

if(substr($output, 0, 16) == 'No syntax errors') {
    echo('OK');
}else {
    echo('KO');
}
```

But the exceptions still the right way to manage errors.

Answer (score -1):

what about checking if the `file_exists()` before using `require()`.

```
if (file_exists("./formfunctions/" . $file . ".php")) {

 try{
    require "./formfunctions/" . $file . ".php";
    $result = $returnValue;
    } catch(Throwable $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do not know :/ (I didn't make down vote). Tried this, but it doesn't work for me. I want to check if the existing file is running without issues. If there is an error somewhere (not syntax one), trow error, continue with the rest of the script and trow error for this file.